# Filter for admin site, How works FilterSpec,RelatedFilterSpec,ChoicesFilterSpec i.e?

Tags: python, django, django-admin-filters

Yesterday, I collided with the problem when I was trying to write special filter for my admin site in Django.

I have 3 models:

```
class ShopInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword1 = models.CharField(max_length=4096,  blank=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Products)


class Products(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(ShopInfo)
```

In Admin site, on the Keyword edit page, I want create a filter for Keywords by shop.
In other words, I want to see full list of shops in filter list on the right of page, when you click on that we will choose the Keywords belonged this shop.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need any custom FilterSpecs for that. You can just use django's join syntax in your list_filter property for your ModelAdmin. For example:

```
class KeywordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['product__shop']
```